# Call a activity's function from the other

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B. Activity A starts activity B. Now I'm in B, how to call A's function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless function is static you are out of luck. I suggest that you place necessary functions in Application object or make them static.

Note that activity not on top of the stack can be destroyed at any time.

Comment: +1, put the relevant code in a separate class or if it's really severe put it in a Service subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't...but what you can do is this:

1. You can create a `BaseActivity` with the functionality you want in both A and B, and then have both A and B extend this class.
2. You can pull the common code into its own class, and have it be a member variable on both A and B.

The first way is probably preferred, as it may be difficult to get your common code class into the activities.